# Table valued function does not return data

Tags: sql-server

Testing my first Table Valued Function, I get no data, even while the SELECT works.
Not returning anything:

```
select * from GetMvtHistory('C1505 BLACK')
```

Returning correct data:

```
select row_number() OVER (order by DocId) as Id, detailId, Quant, 0 as Cumul
    FROM vwDetailsHist
    WHERE refer = 'C1505 BLACK'
    ORDER BY DocId;
```

TVF code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMvtHistory]
(@Ref char(10))
RETURNS @MvtHist table
(
Id int,
[DetailId] int NULL, 
[Quant] int NULL, 
[Cumul] int NULL
)
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
INSERT into @MvtHist
    select row_number() OVER (order by DocId) as Id, detailId, Quant, 0 as Cumul
        FROM vwDetailsHist
        WHERE refer = @Ref
        ORDER BY DocId;

RETURN
```

**What am I missing** ?? Thanks !

Comment: What type is vwDetailsHist.refer?

Comment: Also this doesn't need to be a multi statement TVF. Inline TVFs generally perform better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made the parameter a `char(10)`. I cannot imagine that is the data type you need. You should probably use the same data type that the column has (which should probably be an `nvarchar`).

`'C1505 BLACK'` is 11 chars. Doesn't fit.

Comment: Oooops. I feel stupid now. You're perfectly right. Thanks.  
@Ref is indeed Varchar(15)

Comment: Be sure to fix the string data types to be longer nvarchar types. That gets rid of issues like this and others.

Answer (score 0):

Set `@Ref` parameter to `50` or `higher`. Example:

```
@Ref varchar(500)
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Though if `ref` is indexed and is actually `varchar` rather than `nvarchar` using this datatype can prevent an index seek.